# REST api by query string

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I want to implement a REST service in java to upload or delete a file from a location (URL).

How to do using REST? What is the best approach! Steps/Tutorials to do something similar are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is a style, not a standard, so there are many solutions to your problem.

Also, REST is about managing entities identified by a URL. This doesn't seem to be the purpose of your API.

My first step would be to identify the entity I want to manage, and assign it a URL. Then use the REST verbs for defining operations on this entity. Hope this helps.

The way you're approaching the problem serviceapi/**process** suggests that you're trying to do a RPC style API, not a RESTful one.

Comment: First of all, model your solution as CRUD operations on an entity (find an entity!). Otherwise, you're not using REST.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Spring's MVC approach, you can set the content type as plain text like:

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces ="text/plain" )
     @ResponseBody
     public String process(String url) {
     String result=//process file etc..
           return result;
        }
```